# OpenAPI Generator Gradle Plugin ~ How to apply custom templates

Tags: openapi-generator-gradle-plugin

I am using the OpenAPI Generator Gradle Plugin to generate a html documentation for my project using the html2 generator. Now, I want to use templates to slightly adjust the output (specifically, I want to exchange the outdated and vulnerable jQuery version).

As far as I understand this should work by modifying the `js_jquery.mustache` file, putting it in the correct directory, and then adjusting the `build.gradle` accordingly, so that's what I did:

I made my own version of the `js_jquery.mustache` file and put it in the folder `src\Resources\Documentation\Template\htmlDocs2` (`htmlDocs2` is the exact name of the folder where it is located in the source code of the `openapi-generator` project; I've also tried `html2`, but that didn't work either).

I then added this to the `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        [...]
    }
    
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.openapitools:openapi-generator-gradle-plugin:6.6.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.openapi.generator'

openApiGenerate {
    generatorName = "html2"
    inputSpec.set("$rootDir/src/Resources/Documentation/My.yaml")
    outputDir.set("$rootDir/bin/apiGenerator")
    templateDir.set("$rootDir/src/Resources/Documentation/Template")
}
```

Running the `openApiGenerate` afterwards works. However, the changes I made to the `js_jquery.mustache` file are not reflected in the output. Rather, the output looks like it used the original `js_jquery.mustache` file. So it seems like I'm still missing something or doing something wrong, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after some more experimenting, I found out what I was missing:

It turns out that in `templateDir.set`, I needed to include the `htmlDoc2` as well. I had assumed that this property had to be fed a directory holding multiple templates, but instead it apparently requires the full path to the template matching the chosen generator.

tl:dr: For the above use case, the `openApiGenerate` section in the `build.gradle` needs to look like this:

```
openApiGenerate {
    generatorName = "html2"
    inputSpec.set("$rootDir/src/Resources/Documentation/My.yaml")
    outputDir.set("$rootDir/bin/apiGenerator")
    templateDir.set("$rootDir/src/Resources/Documentation/Template/htmlDocs2")
}
```

Alternatively, the contents of the `htmlDocs2` folder need to go directly into the `Template` folder